# How to redirect to different pages based on Firebase Information

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjS5L.png)

For my project, I would like to allow users to login to respective homepages based on their identity (eg: Buyer,Seller) after clicking a button with the firebase sign in with email and password method. I am unsure about the way to get it done.

Here's what I tried and I was directed to SellerHomepage for both Buyers and Sellers.

```
 fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                  if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                      db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
                      db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                              for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {
                                  String userType = ds.child("type").getValue(String.class);
                                  if (userType.equals("Buyer")) {
                                      startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BuyerHomepage.class));
                                  }
                                  else if(userType.equals("Seller")) {
                                      startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SellerHomepage.class));
                                  }
                              }
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                          }
                      });
                  }
                  else {
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error !" +task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Danial check this code

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
            String mail=dataSnapshot.child("type").getValue().toString();
             if (userType.equals("Buyer")) {
          startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BuyerHomepage.class));
                              }
                            if(userType.equals("Seller")) {
           startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SellerHomepage.class));
                              }
        }
  
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @Daniel Your database is wrong, what is Banzi? Please explain it

Comment: That's the fullname of the users. I have changed the code from with the push() method so now it displays the unique key for the users instead of the fullname.

Comment: @Daniel I hope when you used the push(), it starts working.

Comment: @Daniel I edited the answer please check it, If you are using push ids instead of "Tester" etc, then this code will be worked :)

Comment: Alright , I will check out the code after my classes. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: @Daniel Your welcome! If the answer is help full mark it accepted :) cheer

Comment: I solved the issue. Thanks for the help bro :)

Comment: You're welcome bro