# Populate array with opposite users with the same location value on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed a dog walking app with a tinder swipe feature. At the moment I have it so that when you log in as a dog walker you are presented with the dog owners and you can swipe whether you like them or not. The problem I am having is that I want to populate the array of the users which are in the same county as the user that is signed in. I currently have the county writing to Firebase via a spinner

```
private void saveUserInformation() {
        fname = mDogNameField.getText().toString();
        bio = mBioField.getText().toString();
        county = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Map userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("fname",dogName);
        userInfo.put("bio", bio);
        userInfo.put("county", county);
```

This is my Swipe activity this is where the functions are to populate the array. Can anyone provide the function I need to populate the array only with the users who have the same county on Firebase as the user signed in.

At the moment the user filters the county of users displayed by a spinner in the activity (not working).

```
package com.example.a117478846_fyp;
//potential matches to user video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTGyUUsOTAQ&t=92s&ab_channel=SimCoder
// adapted this video for matching users https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp61U9sCiTw&list=PLxabZQCAe5fio9dm1Vd0peIY6HLfo5MCf&index=9&pbjreload=101&ab_channel=SimCoder
//setting an image to a card using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2yHW5wuxoE&list=PLxabZQCAe5fio9dm1Vd0peIY6HLfo5MCf&index=12&ab_channel=SimCoder
//setting up chat functionality with video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dC4w04AuOs&list=PLxabZQCAe5fio9dm1Vd0peIY6HLfo5MCf&index=16&ab_channel=SimCoder
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.a117478846_fyp.Utils.SendNotification;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SwipeActivity extends Activity {

    private cards cards_data[];
    private com.example.a117478846_fyp.arrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private int i;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUId;
    private String userId;
    private TextView name;

    private Button btnEdit;
    private Button btnMatches;

    ListView listView;
    List<cards> rowItems;
    private String county;
    Spinner spinner;


    private DatabaseReference usersDb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe);

        //save the notificationID to the database
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
        OneSignal.sendTag("User_ID", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        OneSignal.setEmail(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        OneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
        OneSignal.idsAvailable((userId, registrationId) -> FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("notificationKey").setValue(userId));


        Button btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

        Button btnMatches = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMatches);
        usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        checkUserType();

            spinner = findViewById(R.id.spCountyFilter);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.counties, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        county = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


        rowItems = new ArrayList<cards>();


        arrayAdapter = new arrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, rowItems);

        SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);


        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                rowItems.remove(0);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {

                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String userId = obj.getUserId();
                usersDb.child(userId).child("connections").child("no").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(true);

                Toast.makeText(SwipeActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String userId = obj.getUserId();
                usersDb.child(userId).child("connections").child("yes").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(true);
                isConnectionMatch(userId);


                Toast.makeText(SwipeActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
            }
        });


        // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(SwipeActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fabLike = findViewById(R.id.fabLike);
        FloatingActionButton fabNope = findViewById(R.id.fabNope);

        fabLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (rowItems.size() != 0)
                    flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectRight();
            }
        });



        fabNope.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           if (rowItems.size() != 0)
                                               flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();
                                       }
                                   });



        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461357/how-to-redirect-to-different-pages-based-on-firebase-information?noredirect=1&lq=1
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String mail = dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue().toString();

                            if (userType.equals("Dog Walker")) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(SwipeActivity.this, WalkerSettings.class));
                            }
                            if (userType.equals("Dog Owner")) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(SwipeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });



    }









    private void isConnectionMatch(String userId) {
        DatabaseReference currentUserConnectionDb = usersDb.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("connections").child("yes").child(userId);
        currentUserConnectionDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SwipeActivity.this, "New connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").push().getKey();

                    usersDb.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("connections").child("matches").child(currentUId).child("ChatId").setValue(key);
                    usersDb.child(currentUId).child("connections").child("matches").child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("ChatId").setValue(key);


                    SendNotification sendNotification = new  SendNotification();
                    sendNotification.SendNotification("check it out!", "new Connection!", dataSnapshot.getKey());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }


    private String userType;
    private String oppositeUserType;

    public void checkUserType() {
        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference userDb = usersDb.child(user.getUid());
        userDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue() != null) {
                        userType = dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue().toString();
                        switch (userType) {
                            case "Dog Owner":
                                oppositeUserType = "Dog Walker";
                                break;
                            case "Dog Walker":
                                oppositeUserType = "Dog Owner";
                                break;
                        }
                        getOppositeUserType();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void goToMatches(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SwipeActivity.this, MatchesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }




    private void getOppositeUserType() {
        usersDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue() != null) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("no").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("yes").hasChild(currentUId) && dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue().toString().equals(oppositeUserType)) {
                        String profileImageUrl = "default";
                        //   if(dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue() != null){
                        if (!dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().equals("default")) {
                            profileImageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();

                        }


                        cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("fname").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("county").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("bio").getValue().toString(), profileImageUrl);
                        rowItems.add(item);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {


            }

        });


    }









    }
```

Logcat:

```
E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5c8c22f
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2712 bytes, containing 1 windows, 8 views
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2800 bytes, containing 1 windows, 8 views
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( TTGly8zrzmSqahuUnbBqlmEFAHA3 ).
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5af3b5a
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "county"' at Users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app ONESIGNAL_SDK_FCM_APP_NAME
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
I/chatty: uid=10085(com.example.a117478846_fyp) RenderThread identical 2 lines
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
I/chatty: uid=10085(com.example.a117478846_fyp) RenderThread identical 1 line
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e2855a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e283450)
```

Firebase Structure:

```
  "Users" : {
    "J2rOt1In1uV9ERlL1Ue9qhLANW22" : {
      "bio" : "default",
      "county" : "Limerick",
      "email" : "117340543@umail.ucc.ie",
      "fname" : "Brian",
      "lname" : "O Sullivan Student",
      "password" : "password",
      "phone" : "0000",
      "profileImageUrl" : "default",
      "userType" : "Dog Walker"
    },
    "QXFyepCTaca4Oo0EbXYDwhExdR02" : {
      "bio" : "default",
      "county" : "Limerick",
      "email" : "brianosullivan429@gmail.com",
      "fname" : "Brian",
      "lname" : "O Sullivan",
      "password" : "password",
      "phone" : "0000",
      "profileImageUrl" : "default",
      "userType" : "Dog Walker"
    },
    "TTGly8zrzmSqahuUnbBqlmEFAHA3" : {
      "bio" : "default",
      "county" : "Limerick",
      "email" : "adammurphy10@gmail.com",
      "fname" : "enter your dogs name!",
      "lname" : "Murphy",
      "name" : "Adam",
      "notificationKey" : "59ad2554-0bb4-42e2-b451-8d27f56c9703",
      "password" : "password",
      "phone" : "00000",
      "profileImageUrl" : "default",
      "userType" : "Dog Owner"
    },
    "wovjQgVZ5hQFQCyHQPPywhK9oqF2" : {
      "bio" : "Test",
      "county" : "Cork",
      "email" : "mareemurphy9@gmail.com",
      "fname" : "Alexa",
      "lname" : "Jones",
      "notificationKey" : "59ad2554-0bb4-42e2-b451-8d27f56c9703",
      "password" : "password",
      "phone" : "99999",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fyp-35227.appspot.com/o/profileImages%2FwovjQgVZ5hQFQCyHQPPywhK9oqF2?alt=media&token=2bde226b-3472-49cb-be46-0db8eea8854f",
      "userType" : "Dog Walker"
    }
  },
  "WalkersAvailable" : {
    "wovjQgVZ5hQFQCyHQPPywhK9oqF2" : {
      ".priority" : "9q9k7zfnqy",
      "g" : "9q9k7zfnqy",
      "l" : [ 37.3532517, -121.8243483 ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a database query, which allows you to order and filter data. If each child node under `/users` has a `county` property, then you will need to take two steps:

1. Determine the county of the current user.
2. Order and filter on that county.

Assuming you have taken step 1 and put the value in a `county` variable, step 2 is:

```
usersDb.orderByChild("county").equalTo(county).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    ...
```

The rest of your code can remain unchanged.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the help. Would I create a new function like my getOppositeUserType() ? I have a county variable in my code, is that incorrect? Would I call the function then in the onCreate? Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: This query replaces your existing `usersDb.addChildEventListener(...`, the `county` in my answer needs to be the value that you want to filter on.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am on the right track now. The array is not populating now. Do I have county declared incorrectly? I have it as:     private String county;
        county = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
You can see it in the code above. Is this wrong? Because when I select the county registered to the user on Firebase, the array is not populating.