# Android - Button takes multiple clicks to carry out function

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a save button in my activity and when I click on it I want to go back to the previous activity and save info. I have to click on the button 5/6 times for this to happen. It saves the info everytime but does not go back to the previous activity. Everytime I click the button the data is saved and the same activity is launched again instead of going back to the previous one.

If I click the back button on the emulator it relaunches the same activity 5/6 times before it actually goes back to the previous activity.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


        mNameField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcome);
        mDogNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dogName);
        mBioField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dogBio);


        mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        mBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        mSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        mLogout = findViewById(R.id.logOut);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        getUserInfo();

        mLogout.setOnClickListener(v -> logOut());


        mProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //tells the phone that we need to access other features (gallery in this case)
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
        });


        mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveUserInformation();
                startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,countySelection.class));
            }
        });


            mBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, countySelection.class));
            }
        });
    }









            private void saveUserInformation() {
                fname = mDogNameField.getText().toString();
                bio = mBioField.getText().toString();

                Map userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                userInfo.put("fname", fname);
                userInfo.put("bio", bio);


                mUserDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo);
                if (resultUri != null) {
                    StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId);
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Compressing photo so it fits nicely
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
                    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
                    UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Map newImage = new HashMap();
                                    newImage.put("profileImageUrl", uri.toString());
                                    mUserDatabase.updateChildren(newImage);

                                    finish();
//                                    return;
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    finish();
//                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            resultUri = imageUri;
            mProfileImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
        }
    }

    private void logOut(){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void getUserInfo() {
        mUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                    if (map.get("name") != null) {
                        name = map.get("name").toString();
                        mNameField.setText("Welcome, " + name);
                    }

                    if (map.get("fname") != null) {
                        fname = map.get("fname").toString();
                        mDogNameField.setText(fname);
                    }

                    if (map.get("bio") != null) {
                        bio = map.get("bio").toString();
                        mBioField.setText(bio);
                    }


//                        Glide.clear(mProfileImage);
                    if (map.get("profileImageUrl") != null) {
                        profileImageUrl = map.get("profileImageUrl").toString();
                        switch (profileImageUrl) {
                            case "default":
                                mProfileImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                                break;
                            default:
                                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(profileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

        }
```

Run:

```
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app ONESIGNAL_SDK_FCM_APP_NAME
I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.a117478846_fyp
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "county"' at Users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2040 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2040 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
D/AutofillManager: onActivityFinishing(): calling cancelLocked()
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2040 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
D/AutofillManager: onActivityFinishing(): calling cancelLocked()
D/AutofillManager: onActivityFinishing(): calling cancelLocked()
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a117478846_fyp">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".WalkerMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_walker_map" />

        <service android:name=".Service.MyFCMService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".registerOption" />
        <activity android:name=".ViewDogProfile" />
        <activity android:name=".WalkerSettings" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity android:name=".Chat.ChatActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MatchesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".corkSwipe"/>
        <activity android:name=".kerrySwipe"/>
        <activity android:name=".clareSwipe"/>
        <activity android:name=".limerickSwipe"/>
        <activity android:name=".tipperarySwipe"/>
        <activity android:name=".waterfordSwipe"/>
        <activity android:name=".countySelection" />
        <activity android:name=".OwnerMapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterDog" />
        <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword" />
        <activity android:name=".SignIn" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterWalker" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Home Screen" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Previous activity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cork_swipe);

        //save the notificationID to the database
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
        OneSignal.sendTag("User_ID", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        OneSignal.setEmail(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        OneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
        OneSignal.idsAvailable((userId, registrationId) -> FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("notificationKey").setValue(userId));


        Button btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

        Button btnMatches = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMatches);
        usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        checkUserType();

        rowItems = new ArrayList<cards>();







        arrayAdapter = new arrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, rowItems);

        SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);


        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                rowItems.remove(0);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {

                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String userId = obj.getUserId();
                usersDb.child(userId).child("connections").child("no").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(true);

                Toast.makeText(corkSwipe.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String userId = obj.getUserId();
                usersDb.child(userId).child("connections").child("yes").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(true);
                isConnectionMatch(userId);


                Toast.makeText(corkSwipe.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
            }
        });


        // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(corkSwipe.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fabLike = findViewById(R.id.fabLike);
        FloatingActionButton fabNope = findViewById(R.id.fabNope);

        fabLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (rowItems.size() != 0)
                    flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectRight();
            }
        });


        fabNope.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (rowItems.size() != 0)
                    flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();
            }
        });


        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461357/how-to-redirect-to-different-pages-based-on-firebase-information?noredirect=1&lq=1
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String mail = dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue().toString();

                            if (userType.equals("Dog Walker")) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(corkSwipe.this, WalkerSettings.class));
                            }
                            if (userType.equals("Dog Owner")) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(corkSwipe.this, testSettings.class));
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }


    private void isConnectionMatch(String userId) {
        DatabaseReference currentUserConnectionDb = usersDb.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("connections").child("yes").child(userId);
        currentUserConnectionDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(corkSwipe.this, "New connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").push().getKey();

                    usersDb.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("connections").child("matches").child(currentUId).child("ChatId").setValue(key);
                    usersDb.child(currentUId).child("connections").child("matches").child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("ChatId").setValue(key);


                    SendNotification sendNotification = new SendNotification();
                    sendNotification.SendNotification("check it out!", "new Connection!", dataSnapshot.getKey());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }


    private String userType;
    private String oppositeUserType;

    public void checkUserType() {
        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference userDb = usersDb.child(user.getUid());
        userDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue() != null) {
                        userType = dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue().toString();
                        switch (userType) {
                            case "Dog Owner":
                                oppositeUserType = "Dog Walker";
                                break;
                            case "Dog Walker":
                                oppositeUserType = "Dog Owner";
                                break;
                        }
                        getOppositeUserType();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void goToMatches(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(corkSwipe.this, MatchesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }


    private void getOppositeUserType() {
        usersDb.orderByChild("county").equalTo("Cork").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue() != null) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("no").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("yes").hasChild(currentUId) && dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue().toString().equals(oppositeUserType)) {
                        String profileImageUrl = "default";
                        //   if(dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue() != null){
                        if (!dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().equals("default")) {
                            profileImageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();

//                            Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
//                                    .orderByChild("county")
//                                    .equalTo(county);
//                            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

                        }


                        cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("fname").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("county").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("bio").getValue().toString(), profileImageUrl);
                        rowItems.add(item);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {


            }

        });


    }

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            rowItems.clear();

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    };
}
```

county selection activity this is where the user is presented with a map and they click on one of the counties to be presented with users only from that county.

```
package com.example.a117478846_fyp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class countySelection extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button cork, kerry, waterford, tipperary, limerick, clare;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_county_selection);

        cork = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cork);
        kerry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kerry);
        waterford = (Button) findViewById(R.id.waterford);
        tipperary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tipperary);
        limerick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.limerick);
        clare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clare);

        cork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(countySelection.this, corkSwipe.class));


            }


        }); kerry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(countySelection.this, kerrySwipe.class));


            }


        }); waterford.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(countySelection.this, waterfordSwipe.class));


            }


        }); tipperary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(countySelection.this, tipperarySwipe.class));


            }


        }); limerick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(countySelection.this, limerickSwipe.class));


            }


        });

        clare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(countySelection.this, clareSwipe.class));


            }


        });

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get it to save the information and go back to the previous activity on first click?

Comment: Which button are u talkin' about? I see 3 onclick listeners in oncreate activity. I suggest you edit the question to comply with SO standards - noone wants to read full class code, snip out the important parts, remove commented code etc.
Should the saveUserInformation - uploadTask success callback change the activity? If yes, I suggest passing callback function from the calling method (onCreate - clickListener), and call the finish() method in the callback function.

Comment: Apologies about that. I have edited the question. Will you check out my second paragraph. Does the app not know what activity is being directed to when I want  to go to previous activity? I can't just direct to a specific activity because of the way the app is built.

Comment: I have took out all the functions and it's still doing the same

Comment: You are already calling finish() inside saveUserInformation() , there is no need to add this line WalkerSettings.super.finish(); after saveUserInformation() in onClickListener . Also something in your previous activity is triggering the relaunch 5-6 times please add your previous activity code too from where you are starting the intent fro this activity .

Comment: Yeah I just tested moving from an empty activity back to the first activity. So it is the previous activity where the error is. Added now. I have no idea what the issue is

Comment: Sorry, but there's way too much code here for us to efficiently help. Please try to reconstruct the problem in an isolated example, as explained in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to do but it seems very strange when you close { two times, before close () in mBack.setOnClickListener(); take a look at that

Comment: @thiago that is the end of the onCreate. I am trying to go back to the previous activity with the android phones back button and it is not doing that on certain activities and I cannot understand why.

Comment: I'm talking about the } inside listener, can you show all the activity code?

Comment: @thiago I have added all the code for that activity now. I think the problem could be something to do with the activity going back to an activity where an array has to be populated with specific users. I have no explanation why this is an issue but it is the only time it is happening throughout my application.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting multiple activities in a loop:

```
@Override 
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { 
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) { 
    ... 
    startActivity(new Intent(corkSwipe.this, WalkerSettings.class));
```

Which I believe will result in 6 activity instances, that are then closed one by one with finish() call.

Comment: you are correct. I have the same activity 6 times essentially just displaying different users from different locations from firebase using orderbyChild. Terrible programming logic. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: IDK what is the point of the app. I would store the data after change and then started the activities one by one (use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity and then in onActivityResult in the primary activity check, whether you have more data in array to process). Anyways, mark the answer as correct plz.

Comment: Its tinder for dog walking. So each activity represents a different county which you pick from a map image. By clicking on the location it presents you with other users from that location. I have added the activity down the end up above. Should I change them to startactivityforresult? When I fix the problem I'll mark the answer as correct

Comment: All right. Well its hard to say what you want to do with this concrete activity and I usualy get money for programing, but I suggest storing the data array in the primary class instance, then opening 1st activity with startActivityForResult and in onActivityResult pop 1st element of data arr, if data arr not empty, open next activity, which will result in some sort of FIFO buffer...